# Template Syntax Error: Could not pass the remainder

Tags: python, html, django

I am currently coding my first django website, and I am experiencing some troubles with the urls. Basically wrote this in my template.

```
<div class="post-thumbnail"><a href="{{% url 'apps' 'translator' 'phrase' %}}">
```

Here's the urls.py

```
path('apps/', AppsView.as_view(), name= 'apps'), 
path('translator/<str:phrase>/', TranslatorView.as_view(), name='translator'),
```

When the code runs, a Template Syntax Error appears saying it couldn't parse the remainder % url 'apps' 'translator' 'phrase' %' from '% url 'apps' 'translator' 'phrase' %.

I know there's something wrong with the way I wrote the url in the template. However, I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

It should be `{% url '...' %}`, the issue here is that you're providing multiple urls. Read more at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Answer (score 0):

A template *tag* is written between `{% … %}`, not <s>`{{% … %}}`</s>:

```
<a href="{% url 'apps' 'translator' 'phrase' %}">
```

If you use double curly brackets, then it is a [template *variable* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/language/#variables).